# Compile pe-parse library with visual studio 2019 and cmake for x86

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, static-libraries

I'm trying to build [pe-parse](https://github.com/trailofbits/pe-parse) library to do some stuff. I have both Visual Studio 2019 and cmake installed in my desktop. [pe-parse](https://github.com/trailofbits/pe-parse) library git says to compile library with command below.

```
# Compile 64-bit binaries with Visual Studio 2017
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

# Compile 32-bit binaries with Visual Studio 2017
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

I only have Visual Studio 2019 so I compiled with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`. But, library is compiled for 64 bit computers so if I try to use in x86 it shows me the library is for x64 and fails with message below.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct peparse::_parsed_pe * __cdecl peparse::ParsePEFromFile(char const *)" (?ParsePEFromFile@peparse@@YAPAU_parsed_pe@1@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>lib\pe-parser-library.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Workspace\Windows\CPP\MalwareAnalysis\Debug\MalwareAnalysis.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I've installed MSVC v141 - VS2107 C++ x64/x86 build tools(v14.16) but `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` shows me error below.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

Do I have to install Visual Studio 2017 to build library for x86 system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the documentation, generator [Visual Studio 16 2019](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html) is **not longer defaults** to Win32 target platform:

> The default target platform name (architecture) is that of the host and is provided in the `CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT` variable.

For build a project for Win32 on 64-bit host, just pass appropriate `-A` option:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 <other options>
```

---

Generators for **previous** Visual Studio versions still default to Win32. E.g. documentation for generator [Visual Studio 15 2017](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html) says:

> The default target platform name (architecture) is Win32.

Comment: cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 host=x86     Used this still not able to set hostx86 and getting same linker error.

Comment: According to [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509244/3440745) the problem was not in `cmake` parameters but in `cmake-js` wrapper.